# Cost optimization in kind of a bin packing problem

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, evolutionary-algorithm, bin-packing

I have a given number of objects, each with a given size, that I want to place in bins. The bins can be of different but also given sizes. Between too objects there's always a gap of a given size. I would like to solve it using Python as that's the language I know best.

The bins and objects can be considered as having only length. Width and height are constant in such a way that they're irrelevant for the problem.

#### Example:

Gap size: 3mm

Objects:

- 7x 300mm
- 28x 630mm
- 13x 152mm

Bin sizes:

- 1800mm
- 2100mm
- 2400mm
- 2700mm
- 3000mm

Each bin has a price depending on its size. Bin sizes can be used multiple times (3x 1800mm for example).

I need to optimize for a) the best packing of above objects minimizing empty space and b) the best combination of bin sizes (least amount of bins). Ultimate goal is minimizing cost.

How can I approach this problem? I'm thinking of using a combination of bin packing optimizers and some evolutionary strategy. Or would it be better to omit the bin packing optimizer and just go with an evolutionary strategy optimizer (e.g. CMA-ES)?

Comment: Is this the full size (dimensionality) of your problem or is "the actual instance" much larger than this?  I think this is conquerable with an integer program & solver...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem

Comment: similar, but different, I think.  In the classic cutting stock problem, the stock (package in this case) is of fixed size.  This problem has a variety of stock sizes and package sizes

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is the full size of the problem. I'm not 100% sure though if there really isn't anything that I might have overlooked. It's essentially optimizing cost of buying wooden boards and beams by figuring out how much I need of which of the sizes available at the diy store.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would attack this with an evolutionary strategy, and have no experience with CMA-ES, so perhaps there are others who would undertake that.  But this is digestible as an Integer Program, and solves pretty quickly, given a relatively small optimality gap, which prevents it from churning "forever."

Comment: This is sometimes called the multiple length cutting stock problem.

Comment: "multiple length cutting stock problem" seems to be the term I was looking for. Thank you very much, I'll see if I can solve it satisfyingly with Python.

Comment: CMA-ES has - as far as I know - a continuous feature and target domains in order to be able to find the gradients in the solution landscape. I'm not sure if it can be applied to an integer problem... it's been quite a while since I learned about it. I might be wrong.